# shouldn't std::pair<T1,T2> have trivial default constructor if T1 and T2 have?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, default-constructor

I ran into a problem because

```
 std::is_trivially_default_constructible<std::pair<T1,T2>>::value == false;
```

even if

```
 std::is_trivially_default_constructible<T1>::value == true;
 std::is_trivially_default_constructible<T2>::value == true;
```

I failed to find a good reason for this design. Wouldn't it appropriate for `std::pair<T1,T2>` to have a `=default` constructor if `T1` and `T2` have?

Is there a simple work around (simpler than defining my own `pair<>`)?

Comment: Someone should [submit a library issue](https://isocpp.org/std/submit-a-library-issue).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simple reason is: history! The original `std::pair<T0, T1>` couldn't have a trivial default constructor as it had some other constructor. It was defined to initialize its members. Changing this behavior in `std::pair<T0, T1>` for trivially constructable types where people rely on the value getting initialized would be a breaking change.

In addition to the history reason, the default constructor of `std::pair<...>` is defined to be a `constexpr` constructor. A `constexpr` default constructor cannot be defaulted.

I'm not aware of a work-around other than creating a custom class.

Comment: Would using a tuple fix this?

Comment: @NeilKirk: `std::tuple<...>` has a non-defaulted `constexpr` default constructor (actual, `std::pair<...>` default constructor is also `constexpr`; I don't think a `constexpr` constructor can be defaulted). That is, `std::tuple<...>` doesn't provide a trivial default constructor.

Comment: @ Neil Kirk: default constructor constexpr tuple() has the same requirement as for std::pair:  "... Effects: Value initializes each element" (20.4.2.1 n3242), so it can't do nothing and therefore can't be trivial.

Comment: "A constexpr default constructor cannot be defaulted." is a bit of an oversimplification. If all of the non-static data members of `T` have `constexpr` default constructors, then a defaulted default constructor of `T` can be `constexpr`. Indeed, if implicitly defined it *will* be `constexpr` per 12.1/6.

Answer (score 1):

Default constructor of std::pair value-initializes both elements of the pair, first and second, so it can't be trivial.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's the problem.